# Разница вычисление в js и php

Tags: php, javascript

PHP выдаёт **6**:

```
$result_points = 24;
$amount_rur = ceil($result_points * 0.2) + round(($result_points / 100) * 5));
```

JS выдаёт **5**:

```
var result_points = 24;
var amount_rur = Math.ceil(result_points * 0.2) + Math.round((result_points / 100) * 5));
```

Как сделать, чтобы php выдавал то, что и js?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nftEc/ — 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странный у Вас интерпретатор у меня и PHP и JS выдали 6.
Если выполняете в броузере, возможно он неправильно интерпретирует вашу ошибку в синтаксисе:

```
round(($result_points / 100) * 5)) // последняя  скобка лишняя
```